# how to remove widget index wise from Column flutter

Tags: flutter

**here is the list of widgets so i want to remove any widget from this list when user press on the close icon**

**and i also want to get the index of the widget**

```
 List<Widget> _Items = [
      Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
// on tap this widget should be removed from the list
}, child: Icon(Icons.close)),
            ),
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
// on tap this widget should be removed from the list
}, child: Icon(Icons.close)),
            ),
      
    ];



Column(children: _Items,)
```

Comment: you cant get the index when using column.. used ```ListView.builder()```.. i can give an answer in ListView.Builder not on Column

Comment: So what will be the answer for listView.builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `ListView.builder()`. It support get index of list. 
Example:

```
class _TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage> {
  final List<Widget> items = [
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
// on tap this widget should be removed from the list
      }, child: Icon(Icons.close)),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
// on tap this widget should be removed from the list
      }, child: Icon(Icons.close)),
    ),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length, itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return items[index];
          });
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  final List<Widget> items = [
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Icon(Icons.close),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  items.remove(items[index]);
                });
              },
              child: items[index],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```